# How to deduct date and time in one cell

Tags: excel, date, time, excel-formula

Please can you tell me if there is a formula / code that will deduct date and time if date and time are in the same cell.

ie

31/07/2019 15:00:00 less 01/08/2019 16:00:00 - using format (dd/mm/yyyyy hh:mm)

Thank you Marc

Comment: By deduct do you mean subtract? Date/times underlying value in Excel is just a number, which can be easily operated on with addition, subtraction, etc.. If you're having trouble, you might be dealing with text that looks like a date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two dates you're subtracting are in the same cell, I would separate them with `Text to Columns`, reformat to make sure they are both date.

Then (and if they are in different columns) you can just do

`= 1/8/2019 - 31/7/2019` since and this will give you the difference. You can also use `Datedif`